# How do I fix "TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"?

Tags: python, list, methods

I am currently trying to code Uno in python for my Computer science principles class in school and I created a definition to draw cards from the deck into the player's hand and whenever I run the code I keep getting this error. I was just wondering how to fix it because I have tried a couple of things and have gotten nowhere.

I've tried adding items to the player's hand (which starts empty).
I tried using tuples.  I've tried using making the drawing variable a list.  `x` stipulates which player's hand it is while `y` is how many they draw and `z` is what cards are in the deck.

```py
import random
import time
import sys

def draw_cards(x,y,z):
  for q in range(y):
    draw = random.choice(z)
    x = x.insert(0,draw)
    z = z.remove(draw)
  return x,z

cards_in_deck = ["red 0","red 1", "red 2", "red 3", "red 4", "red 5","red 6","red 7", "red 8", "red 9", "red skip", "red reverse","red +2","wild","yellow 0","yellow 1", "yellow 2", "yellow 3", "yellow 4", "yellow 5","yellow 6","yellow 7", "yellow 8", "yellow 9", "yellow skip", "yellow reverse","yellow +2","wild","green 0","green 1", "green 2", "green 3", "green 4", "green 5","green 6","green 7", "green 8", "green 9", "green skip", "green reverse","green +2","wild","blue 0","blue 1", "blue 2", "blue 3", "blue 4", "blue 5","blue 6","blue 7", "blue 8", "blue 9", "blue skip", "blue reverse","blue +2","wild","red 1", "red 2", "red 3", "red 4", "red 5","red 6","red 7", "red 8", "red 9", "red skip", "red reverse","red +2","wild +4","yellow 1", "yellow 2", "yellow 3", "yellow 4", "yellow 5","yellow 6","yellow 7", "yellow 8", "yellow 9", "yellow skip", "yellow reverse","yellow +2","wild +4","green 1", "green 2", "green 3", "green 4", "green 5","green 6","green 7", "green 8", "green 9", "green skip", "green reverse","green +2","wild +4","blue 1", "blue 2", "blue 3", "blue 4", "blue 5","blue 6","blue 7", "blue 8", "blue 9", "blue skip", "blue reverse","blue +2","wild +4"]

player_hand = []
ai_dusty_hand = []
ai_cutie_hand = []
ai_smooth_hand= []

draw_cards(ai_dusty_hand,7,cards_in_deck)
draw_cards(ai_cutie_hand,7,cards_in_deck)
draw_cards(ai_smooth_hand,7,cards_in_deck)
draw_cards(player_hand,7,cards_in_deck)
```

I expected the result to be each player having a starting hand but, the output ends in an error,

Comment: The posted code never tries to use the method `len` on anything, so it is not clear where this error is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Lists in Python are mutable. So when you manipulate a list (even within the scope of a function) it will reflect everywhere that list is referenced.

```
x = x.insert(0,draw)
z = z.remove(draw)
```

These lines of code are assigning the return of the method calls on the list. Both of these method calls don't return anything (therefore they return `None`).

Remove the assignments of the lists in your function.

Comment: Therefore, the solution is to remove the assignment statement from the calls, right? You mentioned what was wrong, but not how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from these two lines, because remove does not return the list :

```
x = x.insert(0, draw)
z = z.remove(draw)
```

`insert` and `remove` do not return anything.  Do not reassign `x` and  `z` and it should work:

```
x.insert(0, draw)
z.remove(draw)
```

In addition, you should return `z` to save the remaining cards:

```
def draw_cards(x,y,z):
  for q in range(y):
    draw = random.choice(z)
    x.insert(0,draw)
    z.remove(draw)
return z

cards_in_deck = draw_cards(ai_dusty_hand,7,cards_in_deck)
cards_in_deck = draw_cards(ai_cutie_hand,7,cards_in_deck)
cards_in_deck = draw_cards(ai_smooth_hand,7,cards_in_deck)
cards_in_deck = draw_cards(player_hand,7,cards_in_deck)
```

Comment: By that token, the `insert` call shouldn't have an assignment as well so this will additionally need to be removed as the method doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thanks for your help!